# Get steady_clock and system_clock at the same time

Tags: c++, synchronization, c++-chrono

My Code looks like:

```
// Next 2 lines should be at the same time
auto nowMonotonic = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
auto nowSystem = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

// Do some calc with nowMonotonic and nowSystem
```

This can happen:

```
auto nowMonotonic = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
// Some other thread/process interrupts this thread for an 
// unspecific amount of time...
auto nowSystem = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

// Do some calc with nowMonotonic and nowSystem
```

I'm working on a (non-realtime) linux system. I'm doing some calculations based on the current `steady_clock` and the current `system_clock`. The result is better than less the jitter between the reading of the two clock is.

**What is the best way to read the two clocks at (nearly) the same time?**

Is there a special system call to do this? Is there a possibility to get the difference of these two clocks in a single system call?

Comment: On a modern preemptive multi-tasking OS it's really impossible. It might be possible if you have a thread with realtime scheduling (see e.g. [`sched_setscheduler`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html) for information on that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do this perfectly, and there is not even a best way.  And the way you have shown is one of the good ways.  If you are willing to trade some run time you can gain some better accuracy in a statistical sense by calling `now()` more than once on each clock and averaging the results.

For example:

```
std::pair<std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point,
          std::chrono::system_clock::time_point>
combined_now()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto u0 = system_clock::now();
    auto t0 = steady_clock::now();
    auto t1 = steady_clock::now();
    auto u1 = system_clock::now();
    return {t0 + (t1-t0)/2, u0 + (u1-u0)/2};
}
```

This is not necessarily better than what you have.  But it is another tool in the toolbox to be aware of.  As always, use tests with your specific use case to decide what is best for you.

Comment: While being disappointed that there is no better solution, I very much like your suggestion. Do you - or does anyone - have a semi-empirical suggestion to what extend statistically averaging is sensible? i.e. You use only 2 data points, but one could be willing to allow X seconds to get a really good "synchronicity" at a start of an experiment or a few times a day....